# Customizing discussions list in SP2013 with JsLink

Tags: development, list, 2013, custom, community

I'm working on a community site and was looking at ways to modify UI of the discussion list that is presented to the user (and possibly more going forward).

It is my understanding according to the articles below that lists can be customized using JSLink (the new client-side rendering mechanism).

http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2012/js-link-for-sharepoint-2013-web-partsa-quick-functional-primer/

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html

The articles I've found seem to address the creating of a basic custom list and then modifying the look of that but I've yet to find guidance on modifying a built in list - such as the discussion list on the main community page.

How would one go about finding the correct values to put in the ListTemplate (such as Type) and is there any guidance on building up your templates in JS?

Answer (score 2):

The technique is called Client Side Rendering (i've posted a complete example which makes a carousel View from an Announcements list - you need to follow the same approach).

In simple words you are specifying the way each fields is rendered in the browser, in adition to which you could change/manipulate list heading/footer - all with the power of Javascript templating, Knockout, and most important - full CSOM!

Have a look at this article and download the source code to get full insight - http://nettitude.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/creating-a-carousel-in-a-sharepoint-app-using-client-side-rendering/

Just be aware that you do not need to create SharePoint App, but you could safe use the artifact within, such as ListInstance, ListTemplate, Custom Actions, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand that you are creating a custom list in this instance. Is that right? Can you offer any direction in terms of changing the behaviour of an existing list such as the discussion list?